# Скрипт. Перемножить содержимое дочерних блоков только внутри родительского

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть несколько однотипных (родительских блоков) внутри которых содержатся 2 дочерних блока, содержащие в себе разные числа, задача состоит в том, чтобы скрипт перемножал числа по клику на родительский блок, и помещал их в поле находящееся внутри этого же родительского блока.
Сейчас написанный скрипт почти работает, только по клику перемножаются числа из первого родительского блока а результат заносится в дочерние поля всех родительских блоков.
Вот небольшая заготовка и что пробовал.

Сам код:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="priceday">3 000руб.</div>
    <input name="duration_display" value="2дн."  class="form-text required valid"></input>
    <div class="summ-date">
        <label class="" for="edit-summ">Сумма заказа:</label>
        <input readonly="readonly" id="summ" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="summ" value="0" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text"></input>
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="priceday">5 000руб.</div>
    <input name="duration_display" value="2дн."  class="form-text required valid"></input>
    <div class="summ-date">
        <label class="" for="edit-summ">Сумма заказа:</label>
        <input readonly="readonly" id="summ" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="summ" value="0" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text"></input>
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="priceday">15 000руб.</div>
    <input name="duration_display" value="2дн."  class="form-text required valid"></input>
    <div class="summ-date">
        <label class="" for="edit-summ">Сумма заказа:</label>
        <input readonly="readonly" id="summ" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="summ" value="0" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text"></input>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Что пробовал:

```
$('.block').click(function(){
    var price = $('.block .priceday').html(); 
    price=price.replace(/руб\./, "")
    price=price.replace(/ /, "")
    //alert(price);
    var day = $('input.form-text').val(); 
    day=day.replace(/дн\./, "");
    sum=Math.round(day*(price));
    $('input#summ').val(sum+" руб.");
    $('#summvar').val(sum);
});
```

Comment: `$('.block .priceday').html()` здесь берешь данные со всех сразу, `day*(price)` вот тут умножаешь строку на строку

Comment: у меня так и написано

Comment: причем тут java?

Comment: еще не вижу где элемент с `id=summvar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` внутри обработчика указывает на элемент по которому кликнули. Искать нужно внутри него, т.е. вместо

```
var price = $('.block .priceday').html();
```

нужно

```
var price = $(this).find('.priceday').html();
```

кроме того. дальше вы пытаетесь умножать строки, скорее всего получите *NaN*, чтобы этого избежать используйте *parseInt* или *parseFloat* в зависимости от того какое число нужно. целое или дробное.

```
price = parseFloat($(this).find('.priceday').html().replace(' ',''));
day = parseInt($(this).find('input.form-text').val(), 10);
```

**UPDATE:** id - должен быть уникальным на странице. поэтому вместо `id="summ"` нужно использовать `class="summ"` и искать его внутри `this`

```
$(this).find('.summ').val('значение');
```

Comment: спасибо) NaN не получаю решил проблему перезаписью можете по ссылке выше посмотреть)

Comment: в данном случае просто везет, но лучше всегда переводить в числа, чтобы не было неожиданностей. например при сложении

Comment: "еще не вижу где элемент с id=summvar" это у меня поле которое потом в адресную строку уйдет. Которую потом примет форма обратной связи. Дальше все отлично работает)) Нужно было вопрос решить только с  тем чтобы результат считался внутри конкретного блока)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4fngmcuu/2/ а вот посмотрите, как сейчас срабатывает, меня в принципе и так устраивает. Но на будущее хотелось бы знать, как сделать, чтобы результат попадал в соответствующее родительскому блоку поле

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, я в секции UPDATE - добавил: подход тот же, первое, вместо id использовать class, второе - искать только внутри блока по которому щелкнули

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов и не забудь в разметке вместо `id="summ"` писать `class="summ"` иначе `$(this).find('.summ')` ничего не выберет

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, пример https://jsfiddle.net/4fngmcuu/4/

Comment: отлично то что надо, благодарю!)